# How to programmatically determine the scope of a bean

Tags: java, spring, scope

I am trying to find out the scope of a bean by its name.

What I found so far is:

```
BeanFactory#isPrototype(String name)
           #isSingleton(String name)
```

In my case I want to find out if the bean is in request scope. There are some internal methods in Spring framework that I could use, but I am wondering if there is a "proper" way of doing it.

Comment: This is just a guess but since regular application code isn't supposed to know about scopes at all, chances are those internal methods are your only option.

Comment: You shouldn't need to discover it at runtime. You're the designer of the application. You should ***already*** know.

Comment: @EJP In my case, in the place where I need to know, I don't. If I knew I would not ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question.

There is no method `isRequst()` in `BeanFactory` because request scope is relevant for web only.

I've just tried to find the way to do this and failed. So, I can suggest you a work-around that will work if you are using annotations. When you get bean instance say `bean.getClass().getAnnotation(Scope.class)`. If this returns `Scope` call `value()`.

This is not "scientific" method, but hopefully good enough for you.

EDIT

Other approach is the following. The request scope beans are stored in request attribute. I do not remember its name now but you can easily find it yourself, just examine your request in debugger. Then check that reference to your bean is there. This method is probably better but requires some efforts to investigate the request attribute and the data structure used by Spring framework.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution will work for instances of [`ConfigurableApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public String getScope(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, String sourceBean) {
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = context.getBeanFactory().getMergedBeanDefinition(sourceBean);
    return beanDefinition.getScope();
}
```

By consulting the `BeanDefinition`s, this solution will also work for custom bean scopes.